# Distance between a point and a conic curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, qcqp

I have a point $r=(100,0)$ and want to find the closest point to it from this set:

$$k = \{(a,b) : b^2=1+a/4\}$$

where $a$ belongs to $[-4,0]$.

I thought about defining function $h(x)=|r-x|$, and using Lagrange multipliers to locate minimum point. However, I calculated the gradient of both and everything fine but i don't know how to force $a$ to be in $[-4,0]$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove the constraint $a \in [-4,0]$, what set do you have? Have you plotted it?

Comment: i think without the [-4,0] it would be an ellipse? however i'm looking for way that only involved substitutions and algebra with no plotting. thanks though

Comment: It's a conic, but certainly not an ellipse. If you can't picture what the solution looks like, it's harder to solve the problem.

Comment: If you parametrize the set, then you have a 1-dimensional optimization problem without any equality constraints. Minimize the squared distance, rather than the distance.

Answer (score 0):

The squared distance between a free point $(x,y)$ and the fixed point $(100,0)$ is $(x-100)^2 + y^2$. If the free point travels along the curve $y^2 = 1 + \frac{x}{4}$, then the squared distance is

$$f (x) := (x-100)^2 + 1 + \frac{x}{4}$$

where $x \in [-4,0]$. If the minimum is attained in the interior of $[-4,0]$, then it can be found by making the first derivative vanish. If the minimum is not attained in the interior, then it is attained on the boundary. Hence, one must evaluate $f$ at three values to find the minimum.